# MATLAB - Remove Leading and Trailing Zeros From a Vector

Tags: matlab, vector, strip

I have a wavelet function with leading and trailing zeros.  I would like to strip all the zeros which occur before or after the wavelet. However, I would not like to remove any zeros within the wavelet itself.  To simplify, let's say I have the following 1x11 vector:

```
0 0 0 -2 -1 0 -1 -2 0 0 0
```

After removing leading and trailing zeros the vector should be:

```
-2 -1 0 -1 -2
```

My actual vectors are large and performance is my primary concern.  I am a MATLAB novice and would appreciate any tips on how to accomplish this task as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this

```
 y = x(find(x,1,'first'):find(x,1,'last'));
```

The `find(x,1,'option')` command gives you first and last non-zero indices.

Comment: what if i want to do it with a matrix?

Answer (score 11):

```
i1 = find(X, 1, 'first')
```

will give you the index of the first non-zero element of `X`

```
i2 = find(X, 1, 'last')
```

will give you the index of the last one.  Then

```
X(i1:i2)
```

will give you the array with the leading and trailing zeros stripped.