# Trim Binary Matrix in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I have a binary matrix like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and I want to trim this matrix (in other words, remove zeroes at the boundaries) to be like:

```
0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0
```

How to do this the "Matlab" way? that's **not to use conventional loops and conditions**.

**To be clearer**, the matrix should be reduced to start from the first column which has at least one `1`, and ends at the last column with the same condition, inclusive. Any column out of this range should be removed. Same rules apply for rows.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your input matrix always have a boundary of `0`s or do you want only to trim the edges which are all `0`s ?

Comment: only the edges which are all `0`s

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488504/matlab-remove-leading-and-trailing-zeros-from-a-vector

Comment: @Junuxx This is a 2-D matrix, so it's not an exact duplicate.

Comment: @shoelzer: You just need to apply the answer to both axes. Yes there is a difference, but it's quite trivial.

Comment: @Junuxx You also have to use `any` to check all rows/cols.

Comment: @Junuxx Because the matrix is 2-D. Otherwise `find` will return a linear index to the 2-D matrix which is not going to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have the data in matrix `M`...

```
x = find(any(M,2),1,'first'):find(any(M,2),1,'last');
y = find(any(M),1,'first'):find(any(M),1,'last');
M(x, y)
```

Or, if you know that there will be a 1 in every row/col except the edges:

```
M(any(M,2), any(M))
```

Comment: Does this work as intended if there's a row/column with all zeroes in the middle?

Comment: This approach will have problem if matrix has additional zero column or row in center of matrix

Comment: @Junuxx Good catch. I saw that myself and fixed it just as you commented.

Comment: +1 for the `any` solution. If the assumption holds it's pretty elegant. But I still think the question is a duplicate :p

Comment: Nice. Good thing is that it could be written as an anonymous function too:  
`trim_mat = @(M) M(find(any(M,2),1,'first'):find(any(M,2),1,'last'), find(any(M),1,'first'):find(any(M),1,'last'));`

Answer (score 1):

Extension to higher dimensions:

Assuming a 3D matrix to be trimmed, this is more straightforward:

```
M=rand(3,3,3); % generating a random 3D matrix
M(2,:,:)=0; % just to make a check if it works in extreme case of having zeros in the         middle

padded = padarray(M,[2 2 2]); % making some zero boundaries

[r,c,v]=ind2sub(size(padded),find(padded));

recoveredM=padded(min(r):max(r),min(c):max(c),min(v):max(v));

check=M==recoveredM  % checking to see if M is successfully recovered
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that `find` can return row and column indices:

```
[r1, c1] = find(x, 1, 'first')
[r2, c2] = find(x, 1, 'last')
x(r1:r2, c1:c2)
```

Comment: This won't work because `find` treats `x` as a linear array and then converts to row/col indices. It breaks on a matrix like `[1 0 0; 1 1 0; 1 0 0]`.