# Cut off leading and trailing zeros from array, only if they exist

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to cut off the leading and/or trailing zeros of an input array that may or may not have them. I have seen the answers to questions like:

[MATLAB - Remove Leading and Trailing Zeros From a Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488504/matlab-remove-leading-and-trailing-zeros-from-a-vector)

And this works fine until my input array doesn't actually start/end with zeros:

```
input = [ 1 2 0 3 4 0 0 0 0 ]
```

If this was my input array, the answer to the above question would cut off values that I need.

Is there a succinct way (i.e. no long 'if' statements) to remove leading/trailing zeros, when there is no guarantee that they will be there?

Edit for clarification:

I know that I can use the `find()` function to get an array of nonzero indexes, and then do something like:

```
indexes = find(input)
trimmed_input = input( indexes(1):indexes(end) )
```

But a problem arises, because I have no guarantee that the input array will have trailing/leading zeros, and may (probably will) have zeros in between nonzero values. So my input array could be one of:

```
input1 = [ 0 0 0 nonzero 0 nonzero 0 0 0 ]  =>  [ nonzero 0 nonzero ]
input2 = [ nonzero 0 nonzero 0 0 0 ]  =>  [ nonzero 0 nonzero ]
input3 = [ 0 0 0 nonzero 0 nonzero ]  =>  [ nonzero 0 nonzero ]

input4 = [ 0 0 0 nonzero nonzero 0 0 0 ]  =>  [ nonzero nonzero ]
input5 = [ 0 0 0 nonzero nonzero ]  => [ nonzero nonzero ]
input6 = [ nonzero nonzero 0 0 0 ]  => [ nonzero nonzero ]
```

And using the method above, on either `input2` or `input3` will trim values that I want to keep.

Comment: No, your approach works. have you tried? show one example where it fails.

Comment: Hmmm, I think you're right... I know there was some reason why I thought that this wouldn't work, maybe I was just thinking about it too hard. edit: I know what happened, I was thinking that I was slicing at, but not including the indexes at for which the array was 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of neat way to do it one-liner at the moment, but i think this should work:

```
if input(1)==0
    start = min(find(input~=0))
else
    start = 1;
end
if input(end)==0
    endnew = max(find(input~=0))
else
    endnew = length(input);
end
trimmed_input = input(start:endnew);
```

- if it starts with 0 you need to find the first non-zero element.
- if it ends with 0 you need to find the last non-zero element.

---

**EDIT**

Ha, found the one liner :)

```
trimmed_input = input(find(input~=0,1,'first'):find(input~=0,1,'last'));
```

No idea of if this is actually fast or is less complex.

---

Another alternative (understood what @jrbedard meant):

```
trimmed_input = input(min(find(input~=0)):max(find(input~=0)));
```

Comment: Yea, that's more or less what I have now, I suppose it wouldn't slow the function down too much, it's just a lot of code to do a relatively simple thing, and not very readable.

Comment: Yeah, I am not too happy with it, and sadly matlab does not ternary operator. I guess you can make them into function and just hide the nasty code.

Comment: Updated to a one-liner, I am so happy with myself.

Comment: Nice, yes I see what @jrbedard meant now, thank you, thats exactly what I was looking for. Very concise, possibly less readable than the if statements though haha

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function.

The index of the last nonzero element is given by:

```
index = max(find(input~=0))
```

and the truncated array is:

```
trunc = input(1,index)
```

Comment: I do not think this will work as it will only find the last non-zero element.

Comment: You can use the `'last'` flag when you use `find` to find the last N nonzero elements. In your case, N is 1...so `index = find(input ~= 0, 1, 'last');`. BTW mpaskov is correct in his statement.