# Deleting first zeros in array

Tags: matlab

I have an array `A=[0,0,0,0,0,0,k,-k,0,0,-k,0,k,...]`. How do I get managed to delete all the zeros in the array before `k` ?

deleting works like this: `A(n)=[];`

In this case `n` should be `[1:6]`.

`find(A==0)` isn't helping.

Thanks!

Comment: This is relevant question [Cut off leading and trailing zeros from array, only if they exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40054494/cut-off-leading-and-trailing-zeros-from-array-only-if-they-exist/) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `'first'` input to `find` to specify that you want the location of the first non-zero. You can then use this to index from this point to the end of the array to remove the zeros.

```
output = A(find(A, 1, 'first'):end);
```